# How to find the function memory map in ARM ELF file?

Tags: c++, c, arm, static-analysis

I am trying to perform loop bound analysis for ARMV7m code using Z3 for a big Framework.
I would like to find the memory address that are used by a certain function inside .elf file
for example in a function foo() I have the below basic block

```
ldr     r1, [r3, #0x20]
strb    r2, [r3, #6]  {__elf_header}
str     r2, [r3, #0x24]  {__elf_header}
str     r2, [r3, #0x20]  {__elf_header}
mov     r3, r1
cmp     r1, #0
bne     #0x89f6
```

How can I get the initial memory location used by this function `[r3, #0x20]` ? Are there memory segements for every function to access or is it random ?
Given that the above basic block is a loop. Is there a way to know the memory address that will be used during its execution ?

Does the compiler for example save a memory location address from 0x20 to 0x1234 to be only accessed during the execution of such basic block ? In another word, Is there a map between a function and the range of memory address used by it ?

Comment: Is elf file fully relocated? Is there a loader involved. Did your os support address randomization, do you compile with special flags like -ffunction-section, ... quite a lot unclarity!

Comment: The .elf file is compiled for bare metal with -ffunction-sections flag for arm-none-eabi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is confusing as to what you are asking.  First off why would any linker put the effort into randomizing things?  Perhaps there is one to intentionally make the output not repeatable.  But a linker is just a program and normally will do things like process the items on the command line in order, and then process each object from beginning to end...not random.

So far the rest of this seems pretty straight forward just use the tools.  Your comment implies gnu tools?  Since this is in part tool specific you should have tagged it as such as you cannot really make generalizations across all toolchains ever created.

```
unsigned int one ( void )
{
    return(1);
}
unsigned int two ( void )
{
    return(2);
}
unsigned int three ( void )
{
    return(3);
}

arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <one>:
   0:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000008 <two>:
   8:   e3a00002    mov r0, #2
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000010 <three>:
  10:   e3a00003    mov r0, #3
  14:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

as shown they are all in .text, simple enough.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c -ffunction-sections so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text.one:

00000000 <one>:
   0:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

Disassembly of section .text.two:

00000000 <two>:
   0:   e3a00002    mov r0, #2
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

Disassembly of section .text.three:

00000000 <three>:
   0:   e3a00003    mov r0, #3
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

and now each function has its own section name.

So the rest relies heavily on linking and there is no one linker script, you the programmer choose directly or indirectly and how the final binary (elf) is built is a direct result of that choice.

If you have something like this

```
.text   : { *(.text*)   } > rom
```

and nothing else with respect to these functions then all of them will land in this definition, but the linker script or instructions to the linker can indicate something else causing one or more to land in its own space.

```
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x1000 so.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000001000
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <one>:
    1000:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
    1004:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00001008 <two>:
    1008:   e3a00002    mov r0, #2
    100c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00001010 <three>:
    1010:   e3a00003    mov r0, #3
    1014:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

and then of course

```
arm-none-eabi-nm -a so.elf
00000000 n .ARM.attributes
00011018 T __bss_end__
00011018 T _bss_end__
00011018 T __bss_start
00011018 T __bss_start__
00000000 n .comment
00011018 T __data_start
00011018 T _edata
00011018 T _end
00011018 T __end__
00011018 ? .noinit
00001000 T one      <----
00000000 a so.c
00080000 T _stack
         U _start
00001000 t .text
00001010 T three    <----
00001008 T two      <----
```

which is simply because there is a symbol table in the file

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 22 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 00001000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     2: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     3: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     4: 00011018     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
     5: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS so.c
     6: 00001000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $a
     7: 00001008     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $a
     8: 00001010     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 $a
     9: 00001008     8 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 two
    10: 00011018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _bss_end__
    11: 00011018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __bss_start__
    12: 00011018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __bss_end__
    13: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _start
    14: 00011018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __bss_start
    15: 00011018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __end__
    16: 00001000     8 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 one
    17: 00011018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _edata
    18: 00011018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _end
    19: 00080000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _stack
    20: 00001010     8 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 three
    21: 00011018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __data_start
```

but if

```
arm-none-eabi-strip so.elf
arm-none-eabi-nm -a so.elf
arm-none-eabi-nm: so.elf: no symbols
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <.text>:
    1000:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
    1004:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
    1008:   e3a00002    mov r0, #2
    100c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
    1010:   e3a00003    mov r0, #3
    1014:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

The elf file format is somewhat trivial you can easily write code to parse it, you do not need a library or anything like that.  And with simple experiments like these can easily understand how these tools work.

> How can I get the initial memory used by this function ?

Assuming you mean the initial address assuming not relocated.  You just read it out of the file.  Simple.

> Are there memory segments for every function to access or is it random ?

As demonstrated above, the command line option you mention later in a comment (should have been in the question, you should edit the question for completeness) does exactly that makes a custom section name per function.  (what happens if you have the same non-global function name in two or more objects? you can easily figure this out on your own)

Nothing is random here, you would need to have a reason to randomize things for security or other, it is more often preferred that a tool outputs the same or at least similar results each time with the same inputs (some tools will embed a build date/time in the file and that may vary from one build to the next).

If you are not using gnu tools then binutils may still be very useful with parsing and displaying elf files anyway.

```
arm-none-eabi-nm so.elf
00011018 T __bss_end__
00011018 T _bss_end__
00011018 T __bss_start
00011018 T __bss_start__
00011018 T __data_start
00011018 T _edata
00011018 T _end
00011018 T __end__
00001000 T one
00080000 T _stack
         U _start
00001010 T three
00001008 T two

nm so.elf (x86 binutils not arm)
00001000 t $a
00001008 t $a
00001010 t $a
00011018 T __bss_end__
00011018 T _bss_end__
00011018 T __bss_start
00011018 T __bss_start__
00011018 T __data_start
00011018 T _edata
00011018 T _end
00011018 T __end__
00001000 T one
00080000 T _stack
         U _start
00001010 T three
00001008 T two
```

Or can build with clang and examine with gnu, etc.  Obviously disassembly won't work, but some tools will.

If this is not what you were asking then you need to re-write your question or edit it so we can understand what you are actually asking.

### Edit

> I would like to know if there is a map between a function and the range of memory address used by it ?

In general no.  The term function implies but is not limited to high level languages like C, etc.  Where the machine code clearly has no clue nor should it and well optimized code does not necessarily have a single exit point from the function, much less a return marking the end.  For architectures like the various arm instruction sets the return instruction is not the end of the "function", there is pool data that may follow.

But let's look at what gcc does.

```
unsigned int one ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x+1);
}
unsigned int two ( void )
{
    return(one(2));
}
unsigned int three ( void )
{
    return(3);
}

arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -S so.c 
cat so.s
    .cpu arm7tdmi
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .eabi_attribute 26, 1
    .eabi_attribute 30, 2
    .eabi_attribute 34, 0
    .eabi_attribute 18, 4
    .file   "so.c"
    .text
    .align  2
    .global one
    .arch armv4t
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu softvfp
    .type   one, %function
one:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    add r0, r0, #1
    bx  lr
    .size   one, .-one
    .align  2
    .global two
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu softvfp
    .type   two, %function
two:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    mov r0, #3
    bx  lr
    .size   two, .-two
    .align  2
    .global three
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .fpu softvfp
    .type   three, %function
three:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    mov r0, #3
    bx  lr
    .size   three, .-three
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 10.2.0"
```

we see this is being placed in the file, but what does it do?

```
    .size   three, .-three
```

One reference says this is used so that the linker can remove the function if it is not used.  And I have seen that feature in play so good to know (you could have looked this up just as easily as I did)

So in that context the info is there and you can extract it (lesson for the reader).

And then if you use this gcc compiler option that you mentioned
-ffunction-sections

```
Disassembly of section .text.one:

00000000 <one>:
   0:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

Disassembly of section .text.two:

00000000 <two>:
   0:   e3a00003    mov r0, #3
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

Disassembly of section .text.three:

00000000 <three>:
   0:   e3a00003    mov r0, #3
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr


[ 4] .text.one
       PROGBITS        00000000 000034 000008 00   0   0  4
       [00000006]: ALLOC, EXEC
  [ 5] .rel.text.one
       REL             00000000 0001a4 000008 08  12   4  4
       [00000040]: INFO LINK
  [ 6] .text.two
       PROGBITS        00000000 00003c 000008 00   0   0  4
       [00000006]: ALLOC, EXEC
  [ 7] .rel.text.two
       REL             00000000 0001ac 000008 08  12   6  4
       [00000040]: INFO LINK
  [ 8] .text.three
       PROGBITS        00000000 000044 000008 00   0   0  4
       [00000006]: ALLOC, EXEC
  [ 9] .rel.text.three
       REL             00000000 0001b4 000008 08  12   8  4
       [00000040]: INFO LINK
```

That is giving us a size of the sections.

In general with respect to software compiled or in particular assembled, assume that a function doesn't have boundaries.  As you can see above the one function is inlined into the two function, invisibly, so how big is an inlined function within another function?  How many instances of a function are there in a binary?  Which one do you want to monitor and know the size of, performance of, etc?  Gnu has this feature with gcc, you can see if it is there with other languages or tools.  Assume the answer is no, and then if you happen to find a way, then that is good.

> Does the compiler saves a memory segment to be only accessed by a certain function ?

I have no idea what this means.  The compiler doesn't make memory segments the linker does.  How the binary is put into a memory image is a linker thing not a compiler thing for starters.  Segments are just a way to communicate between tools that these bytes are for starters code (read only ideally), initialized data, or uninitialized data.  Perhaps extending to read only data and then make up your own types.

If your ultimate goal is to find the bytes that represent the high level concept of "function" in memory (assuming no relocation, etc) by looking at the elf binary using the gnu toolchain.  That is possible in theory.

The first thing we appear to know is that the OBJECT contains this information so that a linker feature can remove unused functions for size.  But that does not automatically mean that the output binary from the linker also includes this information.  You need to find where this .size lands in the object and then look for that in the final binary.

The compiler turns one language into another, often from a higher level to a lower level but not always depends on the compiler and input/output languages.  C to assembly or C to machine code or what about Verilog to C++ for a simulation is that higher or lower?  The terms .text, .data, .bss are not part of the language but more of a habit based on learned experience and helps as mentioned communicate with the linker so that the output binaries can be more controlled for various targets.  Normally as shown above the compiler, gcc in this case, since no generalities can be made in this area across all tools and languages or even all C or C++ tools all the code for all the functions in the source file land in one .text segment by default.  You have to do extra work to get something different.  So the compiler in general does not make a "segment" or "memory segment" for each...In general.  You already solved your problem it seems by using a command line option that turns every function into its own segment and now you have a lot more control over size and location, etc.

Just use the file format and/or the tools.  This question or series of questions boils down into just go look at the elf file format.  This is not a Stack Overflow question as questions seeking recommendations for external information is not for this site.

---

> Does the compiler for example save a memory location address from 0x20 to 0x1234 to be only accessed during the execution of such basic block ? In another word, Is there a map between a function and the range of memory address used by it ?

"save"? the compiler does not link the linker links.  Is that memory "only" accessed during the execution of that block?  Well in a pure textbook theory yes, but in reality branch prediction and prefetch or cache line fills can also access that "memory".

Unless doing self-modifying code or using the mmu in interesting ways you do not re-use an address space for more than one function within an application.  In general.  So function foo() is implemented somewhere and bar() somewhere else.  Hand written asm from the good old days you might have foo() branch right into the middle of bar() to save space, get better performance or to make the code harder to reverse engineer or whatever.  But compilers are not that efficient, they do their best to turn concepts like functions into first off functional(ly equivalent to the high level code) and then second, if desired smaller or faster or both relative to a straight brute force conversion between languages.  So barring inlining and tail (leaf?, I call it tail) optimizations and such, one could say there are some number of bytes at some address that define a compiled function.  But due to the nature of processor technology you cannot assume those bytes are only accessed by the processor/chip/system busses only when executing that function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I edited the question as it seems it was uncear.  I would like to know if there is a map between a function and the range of memory address used by it ?
Does the compiler saves a memory segment to be only accessed by a certain function ?

Comment: That is generally not deterministic

Comment: Is there a way to make it determistic ? or put it under control ?
something like one ----> access ( 0x20  - 0x40)
                       ,two -----> access (0x60 - 0x1000)

Comment: -ffunction-section is IMO the key to solving your problem and you brought it up so I think you basically answered your question.  if you dont understand the simple things I have shown with the tools, whatever your task is that requires/desires this information, you are not ready for.  You first need to understand the concepts, then examine the file format and how that matches what is loaded, and then how to isolate those bytes in whatever way you are planning which has not yet been discussed, not all processors if any can truly "watch" for a wide array of fetching of addresses (outside sims).

Comment: old_timer: in general, if you are confused about a question, I would suggest seeking clarifications in the comments first. You can then give an answer from a position of understanding the problem if sufficient clarity can be obtained. Remember that the purpose of this site is to produce Q&A that shall be useful to other readers, not just one.